# Meaning of joint probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand join probability.

let's assume the $P(X>Y) = \frac{3c}{4}$

could someone explain to me what this means in English terms?

If we are to say both $X$ and $Y$ range from 0-1 and there each represent the degree a person likes a product, what would $P(X>Y)=0.75c$ mean?

Would it be safe to assume that it means that $Y$'s opinion depends on $X$, and they usually like the same kind of products at a $75\%$ chance?

Comment: Let $X$ be an indicator variable that a person is right-handed and $Y$ that a person is left-handed. Then $P(X>Y)\approx 0.9$ or whatever the actual percentage is. $X$ and $Y$ are heavily dependent, but not quite $X+Y=1$ since there are a few ambidextrous people.

Comment: @A.S. and what role does the c play here? just a constant? well what if it was a fraction? wouldn't it change the logic completely?

Comment: I don't know context-specific meaning, but $\frac 3 4 c$ is just a constant.

Answer (score 0):

$\Pr(X{>}Y)=\tfrac 3 4c$ means that there is some constant $c$, and the probability that random variable $X$ is greater than random variable $Y$ is $\tfrac 3 4 c$.

> If we are to say both $X$ and $Y$ range from $0-1$ and there each represent the degree a person likes a product, what would $\Pr(X>Y)=0.75c$ mean?

That the probability that person-x likes the product more that person-y does is $\tfrac 34 c$.

Comment: So does that mean that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent on each other?